# Is the API Confirmation Necessary when unsubscribing via ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Right now when someone unsubscribes, we make an API call to ET and wait until we get a confirmation back from ET that the call has been accepted.  However, the timeout for this is 5 minutes and its creating issues with site performance for us by having too many hanging connections.

My question is, if we simply make the API call, and don't leave the connection open, will this affect the accuracy of changing people from active to unsubscribed in ET, or are we ok to do this?  Will the calls just queue up and update when they are accepted later?

Comment: How are you calling the API right now? Could be a better way to call it, but we arent able to help without code sample.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to use the Asynchronous API. That way you do not have to wait for the actual operation to complete. Your request will simply be queued for execution. You will get an 'OK' response immediately and a request id will be returned to you that you can later use to check on the actual status of the request.

See: [Asynchronous Processing](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/asynchronous_processing/)